# Page is reloading after bootstrap modal('show')

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this form:

```
<form action="someaction" method="post" onsubmit="return f1()">
    etc, etc.
    <button type="submit" id="cambioUsuario" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
</form>

function f1(){
    if((a validation between id from values of inputs) {
        alert("passwords are wrong");
        //$('#modal_error').modal('show');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

With this code, all works when the passwords are not the same in 2 inputs (new password and it's verification input). The `alert` shows up. But if I replace the `alert` with `$('#modal_error').modal('show');` the modal doesn't show up and the form is executed. Any idea? I want to show the modal  with the error, not an alert.

Comment: Because the button is `submit`. You need to add `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: But then nothing happens, I need to submit the form in `else` case

Comment: You need to use Ajax then.

Comment: LOL, no... you are ok, the preventDefault has to be inside the `if`. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/UVrNda/preview

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  var isValid = false;
    if(!isValid) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = false;
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      return false;
  }
  else{
    alert("passwords are right");
  } 
});
```

Essentially, you want to prevent the form from submitting if the passwords do not match, and you want to submit the form if they do match.

This could also be achieved by using e.preventDefault() and having an $.ajax call to your server function.

Here is a little post by Kristina Rajic (found by googling your issue)
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-tell-form-not-to-reload-page-but-open-modal-window

Please let me know if this helps.